# How to change the 'series-1' name on the React AppexChart ?? Please see in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, frontend, apexcharts

Please notice the default text 'series-1' in the photo on React Appex Chart.

I want to replace the default text as I wish. I tried in many ways but I failed. I try to find in the documentations but the documentation is not enough clrear. https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/semi-circle-gauge/
I just want to the chart but please notice in my pic. the pic and the documentation is not same. please help me to solve the problem.

[image: this is the pic]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactApexChart, { Props } from "react-apexcharts";

class ApexChart extends React.Component {
   options: Props = {
      series: [25],
      options: {
         chart: {
            type: "radialBar",
            offsetY: -20,
            sparkline: {
               enabled: true,
            },
         },
         plotOptions: {
            radialBar: {
               startAngle: -90,
               endAngle: 90,
               track: {
                  background: "#e7e7e7",
                  strokeWidth: "97%",
                  margin: 5, // margin is in pixels
                  dropShadow: {
                     enabled: true,
                     top: 2,
                     left: 0,
                     color: "#999",
                     opacity: 1,
                     blur: 2,
                  },
               },
               dataLabels: {
                  name: {
                     show: false,
                  },
                  value: {
                     offsetY: -2,
                     fontSize: "22px",
                  },
               },
            },
         },
         grid: {
            padding: {
               top: -10,
            },
         },
         fill: {
            type: "gradient",
            gradient: {
               shade: "light",
               shadeIntensity: 0.4,
               inverseColors: false,
               opacityFrom: 1,
               opacityTo: 1,
               stops: [0, 50, 53, 91],
            },
         },
         labels: ["One"],
      },
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div id="chart">
            <ReactApexChart
               options={this.options}
               series={this.options.series}
               type="radialBar"
               width={200}
               height={200}
            />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default ApexChart;
```

Comment: Can you provide some codesandbox with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I created a working sandbox for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sara-flce0x?file=/src/App.js)

I was able to recreate your behavior and when I put everything into state it just start working. I hope that sandbox will help you. Now you can modify label.

Comment: Sir cloud you help me with the typescript?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using typescript :(